# jbehave + thucydides: how to override 300s timeout

Tags: selenium, jbehave, webautomation, thucydides

I'm using thucydides jbehave plugin to run Selenium tests. However, I can't run tests longer than 5 min in total due to jbehave timeout. I can't figure out how can thucydides/jbehave should be configured to override this limitation. Selenium tests use to be longer that 5 mins, so that should be an actual problem for many people.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To override the timeout the user should add thucydides.properties file to the main folder of the project (if you use thucidides jbehave archetype, there is no such file by default).

set, for instance, story.timeout.in.secs=3000 and save the file. the timeout parameter will be overriden

Comment: the default value of the parameter was 300 s, i.e. 5 mins

Answer (score 0):

To overide the timeout we can use the following :

```
 @Override
        public Embedder configuredEmbedder(){

StoryTimeouts.TimeoutParser t=new StoryTimeouts.TimeoutParser() {
                @Override
                public boolean isValid(String timeout) {
                    return true;
                }

                @Override
                public long asSeconds(String timeout) {
                    return 500; <--- Storytimeout 
                }
            };

            embedder.useTimeoutParsers(t);
}
```